# Using cocoon gem to add nested forms. Facilities will not save unless a Toilet is created first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

I'm going off by the tutorial that's in the cocoon gem. When trying to create a Toilet the facilities that I'm adding won't save unless the Toilet is created first. I was thinking that it should have been created together as is. Is there a way to save the facilities when creating the toilet?

To not get things confused

```
class Toilet < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :facilities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :facilities, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
 end

 class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :toilet
 end
```

Toilet controller

```
def new
 @toilet = Toilet.new
end

def create
 @toilet = Toilet.new(toilet_params)
 if @toilet.save
  redirect_to @toilet
 else
  render :new
 end
end

private
 def toilet_params
  params.require(:toilet).permit(:name, :location, facilities_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
 end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :facilities do |facility| %>
 <%= render 'facility_fields', :f => facility %>
<% end %>
<div class='links'>
 <%= link_to_add_association 'add facility', f, :facilities %>
</div>
 <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

_facility_fields.html.erb

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
 <%= f.inputs do %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove facility", f %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Short version, yes you can save both at the same time ...Long version:  Generically, you can definitely bring up the new action, then dynamically add fields before ever committing the record - then save both the parent & the nested fields / model at the same time, for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wesley, yes - you should be able to save both parent & nested at the same time.  Long version: Yes, you can create a new record, before saving it, dynamically add some nested content & for the first time for either, save them both at the same time.

I believe your issue is probably in the `_facility_fields.html.erb` ... you have a `<% f.inputs do %>` that looks out of place or is just setup wrong.  As you already have a do loop wrapping your `render` command, you shouldn't need this other `do` loop.  That also means you want to remove the `end` thing from the template just above the `/div`.

```
_facility_fields.html.erb

<div class='nested-fields'>
 <%= f.inputs do %>             // Issue is this line
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove facility", f %>
 <% end %>                      // Remove this too afterwards
</div>
```

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. I found a simple solution to this [here](https://www.google.com). In the Facility model, I would add `belongs_to :toilet, optional: true` . It's Rails 5 related.

Comment: Your link just goes to google, not a particular search or page, but nice sleuthing - had a slew of fun with rails 5 myself, but haven't used the optional boolean yet :)